# Stripe fixed-price subscription elements

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I don't know the  flow how subscription works in stripe and how to update credit card details, price, billing cycle of a subscription. Will they debit amount on subscription or after first billing cycle. And it will be helpful if you have examples in NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

There is a repo with various demos for any api-server implementation you would like, which includes nodeJS:
https://github.com/stripe-samples/subscription-use-cases/tree/master/fixed-price-subscriptions

Billing cycle is setup on stripe when you setup the product, and the demo includes a provision for updating plans